# Getting line_items from an order in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have an built an app running on a shopify store that posts paid orders to a third party script that collects the data from that post and then sends it on to a third party order/stock management software.
My issue is that I can get all of the data out of the post with the exception of the line_items.
The [line_items] are present in the json post, but I cant seem to extract those line items, nothing I try seems to work.

Current I have this in place;

```
$orderItems = $order["line_items"];
foreach($order["line_items"] as $i=>$item) { info("ITEM...");
```

The *info* method simply posts the text "ITEM..." to a log file so I can see that *foreach line_items* works.  My order has 2 line_items and in the logs, "ITEM..." appears twice.  So this code appears to be doing what it should.
The issue is that when I try and place anything relating to the line_items themselves, SKU for example, I get nothing back.  Anyone see what I am missing here???

Apologies if I've not explained this too well

Comment: info($line_item['id'])  

Have you tried this ? what you are getting when you try above code ?

Comment: HI, thanks for taking the time to reach out.  If I run my code above, the log file prints this;

`28/Jan/2020 12:14:25 > ITEM...
28/Jan/2020 12:14:25 > ITEM...`

because the test order I place has two line_items.  So my issue seems to be how to loop through line_items correctly.